# Access Azure SQL Database from LAMP localhost in PHP

Tags: php, sql, azure, get, lamp

I would like to connect to by Azure SQL database by using a PHP-Script. I execute the following script by using LAMP:

```
<?php
$serverName = "tcp:***.database.windows.net, 1433";
$connectionOptions = array("Database" => "TryMe",
                           "UID" => "***@serverID",
                           "PWD" => "***");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if($conn === false)
{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Of course I checked the firewall rules on Azure. I allowed my IP to access the server.
But I'm getting the error message:

> GET http://localhost/Ionic/test.php in the web console.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your full error message...also, did you install the driver, right? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: GET http://localhost/Ionic/test.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 0ms]
It's the only message here.

Comment: Are you following these steps? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt720665.aspx ...did you install the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `sqlsrv_connect` requires the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) which is only enabled in Windows system. As you are working in LAMP environment, you can try to use [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) extension and [Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160).